# Google App Engine module's routing is not working

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a demo application written in Python and running on Google App Engine. This app has 3 modules. I added a configuration file to configure module's routing but it's not working. This file called dispatch.yaml looks like this:

```
application: dotted-lexicon-638

dispatch:
  - url: "dotted-lexicon-638.appspot.com/"
    module: default

  - url: "dotted-lexicon-638.appspot.com/list*"
    module: list

  - url: "dotted-lexicon-638.appspot.com/logs*"
    module: logs
```

I deployed this file using "appcfg.py update_dispatch project_dir" command

if you go to "http://list.dotted-lexicon-638.appspot.com" and "http://logs.dotted-lexicon-638.appspot.com"
you can see that both modules are working.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with yaml to say, but your indentation of the different urls is not consistent.

Comment: Also you are not required to specify the "application: dotted-lexicon-638" part. As per https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/routing

Comment: Have you deployed the config? "appcfg.py update_dispatch"

Comment: Yes Greg! I will edit my post. Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you look in the app engine console, does it show the Dispatch item on the left?

Comment: How can I browse my source code on app engine console IanGSY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a path for module routing, it doesn't mean that path maps to the root of the module it just determines which module gets a chance to handle the request. Unless you have code in your list module handling /list, then it will 404.

Comment: Thank you very much! now it's working! I didn't have a /list handling in my list module.